# Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make this work but looks I'm doing something wrong, I've already looked around and can't find or figure out a solution!
Sorry I'm just new on programing;
Got 4 tables and I need to pull some information out :

From table 1 (worksheetsDetails):
I need the product_id product_designation and `SUM(product_quantity)` ordered by product_designation.

From Table 2 (worksheets):
I need to get the worksheet_id from where the table 1 are related.

From table 3 (products):
I need to get the product_price from products who are in the first table and pull a sum of all the products together where the table 4 (work_sites) worksite_id is related.

worksite_id from worksites is related to worksheets table.

I came this far:

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    product_description, 
    SUM(product_quantity) AS quantity 
FROM 
    app_com_worksheetDetails 
LEFT JOIN 
    app_com_worksheet
ON 
    app_com_worksheet.worksheet_id = pp_com_worksheetDetails.worksheet_id
WHERE 
    app_com_worksheet.worksite_id = '$wsi_id'       
GROUP BY 
    product_description"
```

And I'm getting that error!

Please someone can hepl?

Comment: Change to `GROUP BY product_id,product_description`

Comment: thanks it did the work, thanks a lot.